# Get id of inserted object after "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" with SQLite on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy I have the following models (`App <- MarketItem <- MarketItemPriceHistory`):

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Float,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class App(Base):
    __tablename__ = "App"

    appid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"App(appid={self.appid}, name='{self.name}')"


class MarketItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = "MarketItem"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    appid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("App.appid"), nullable=False)
    markethashname =  Column(String, nullable=False)

    app = relationship("App")

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint("appid", "markethashname", name="unique_marketitem"),
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MarketItem(id={self.id}, appid={self.appid}, markethashname='{self.markethashname}')"


class MarketItemPriceHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MarketItemPriceHistory'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    marketitemid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('MarketItem.id'), nullable=False)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    market_item = relationship("MarketItem")
```

And the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import models

from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.dml import OnConflictDoNothing


def get_session(uri: str):
    engine = create_engine(uri, echo=True)
    # By default, SQLite doesn't throw an error when a foreign key references
    # a non-existent id.
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(text('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON'))

    # Create all models
    models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    return Session()


@compiles(Insert)
def suffix_inserts(insert, compiler, **kw):
    # This will basically add "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING" at the end of an insert
    # statement
    insert._post_values_clause = OnConflictDoNothing()
    return compiler.visit_insert(insert, **kw)


session = get_session("sqlite:///__mydatabase.db")

app = models.App(appid=753, name="Steam")
session.add(app)
session.flush()

market_item = models.MarketItem(appid=app.appid, markethashname="HASH NAME 0")
session.add(market_item)
session.flush()

market_item_price_history = models.MarketItemPriceHistory(marketitemid=market_item.id, price=10.5, timestamp=101010)
session.add(market_item_price_history)
session.commit()
```

After creating each object I add them (`session.add(obj)`) and then flush (`session.flush()`) so that objects that have a foreign key can reference them (`models.MarketItem(appid=app.appid, ...)`)

This works fine the first time you run the code, but the second time you get the following error when trying to add create a `MarketItemPriceHistory` object:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
[SQL: INSERT INTO "MarketItemPriceHistory" (marketitemid, price, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT DO 
NOTHING]
[parameters: (0, 10.5, 101010)]
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why does the error occur when trying to create a `MarketItemPriceHistory` object and not a `MarketItem` object?
2. Why is it that in the error message (`[parameters: (<id>=0, <price>=10.5, <timestamp>=101010)]`) `id` is set to 0? SQLite starts table ids from 1, not 0 so it makes no sense to me as for why it's 0.
3. How can I fix this so that it works as expected? (i.e. it fetches the actual id of the `MarketItem` object when trying to create the `MarketItemPriceHistory` object). Ideally I'd like to *not* have to check if the row exists in the database to then be able to create the object

Comment: Works for me - repeating the original inserts completes without error.